# FXML ScrollPane not showing children on its full window

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am working JavaFX FXML for the first time. I am trying to implement a ScrollPane view in the GUI window. Suppose, i want to show an inventory of books. So, the GUI needs to be scroll-able. But my ScrollPane view only showing its children only in a corner of the full GUI, not in the full body.

Following is my FXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" id="AnchorPane" 
        prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="1000.0" pannable="true"
        fx:controller="bookinventory.BooksAllController"
                fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true">
    <content>
        <VBox fx:id="allbookbox" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" > 
          <children>  

        <Label fx:id="nameLbl"
           layoutX="100.0" layoutY="50.0" style="-fx-font-size:15px; -fx-underline: true; -fx-border-width: 0 0 5 0;"
           prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Book Name" textAlignment="LEFT" />

        <Label fx:id="writerNameLbl"
               layoutX="300.0" layoutY="50.0" style="-fx-font-size:15px; -fx-underline: true; -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;"
               prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Writer Name" textAlignment="LEFT" />

        <Label fx:id="genreLbl" style="-fx-font-size:15px; -fx-underline: true; -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;"
               layoutX="500.0" layoutY="50.0"
               prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Genre" textAlignment="LEFT" />

        <Label fx:id="priceLbl" style="-fx-font-size:15px; -fx-underline: true; -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;"
               layoutX="700.0" layoutY="50.0"
               prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Price" textAlignment="LEFT" />

        <Label fx:id="actionLbl" style="-fx-font-size:15px; -fx-underline: true; -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;"
               layoutX="900.0" layoutY="50.0"
               prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Action" textAlignment="LEFT" />

       </children>
    </VBox> 
    </content>

</ScrollPane>
```

the following is the present view of this code:

[image: Present Outcome of the code]

I want a view like the following with vertical scrollbar:

[image: Desired Outcome]

Any help ?

Comment: use more suitable layouts - hint: you expect a horizontal layout, but use a VBox in the fxml ;)

Comment: That looks like you want a table-like UI, in which case you should use a [`TableView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) (which has it's own scrolling functionality built-in).

Comment: The [Working With Layouts in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm) tutorial is incredibly useful.

Comment: Probably want flowpane to allow for a responsive type functionality on the window width.

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra , i am using HBox now, its working :)

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for your idea, it works better :)